# Did Anything Get Deleted From My Pc

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I was moving stuff on my laptop here and there
and then
a folder with 1,600 -1,900 items
in it
I accidentaly moved to the recycle bin
and while the deleting progress bar was going I click on x
cancelled it during process do u think it deleted stuff I mean I dont see anything  in the recycle bin
but I cancelled it mid process so did i delete anything

Answer (score 1):

Deleting files in Windows (assuming that you did not force delete with shift+delete) must move them to the recycle bin.
If it is empty, then the deletion operation was cancelled.

Even if some of the files were actually moved to the recycle bin at first, cancelling this operation simply restored them (as you could have done after the completion of the deletion operation).